# Latitude and Longitude limit max length

Tags: javascript, google-maps, substring

I use google maps Api, in any cases I have value of Latitude and Longitude very long length, for example in Console:

```
results[0].geometry.location.lng()
-74.80111590000001
results[0].geometry.location.lat()
42.055163
```

I want to get max 7 chars after comma

```
results[0].geometry.location.lng().toString().substring(0,10)
"-74.801115"
```

but if the number is negative after comma is not 7 chars,.. for this I can to use indexOf('.') and get 7 chars after comma, but I have very much place where I need to get this values and I want to use something with less code
any proposal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that your lat and long are numbers (if not, there may be better options). Numbers in JS have the [`toFixed()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to convert them into strings with a given number of decimal places.

In your case, `(-74.80111590000001).toFixed(7)` should return the string `"-74.8011159"`, which I believe is what you want. It will also round correctly, which `substring` is not capable of (not being aware of how numbers work).

Answer (score 0):

**[lodash](https://lodash.com/) v3.0.0** has been released with new `String` options last week.

You could use the new `trunc` function:

> `trunc`
>
> Truncates string if it is longer than the given maximum string length.
>   The last characters of the truncated string are replaced with the
>   omission string which defaults to "…".

https://lodash.com/docs#trunc

Example:

```
_.trunc('-74.80111590000001', 7); // -74.801
```

Comment: This has the same problem is using substring: it doesn't recognize the decimal point and trim after that. `Math.round` or `Number.prototype.toFixed` should do the trick well enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more flexible and generic approach, so one function can be reused throughout a script for the purpose of rounding a number to a given number of decimal places.

```
function roundNumber(value, decimals){
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}
```

And to use...

```
var rounded_lng = roundNumber(results[0].geometry.location.lng(), 7);
var rounded_lat = roundNumber(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), 7);
```